# Camera calibration Open CV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to do camera calibration, I have taken the code from open cv documentation. Here is my code -

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
objpoints = []
imgpoints = []
images = glob.glob('/usr/local/share/OpenCV/samples/cpp/chess*.jpg')
img = cv2.imread("2.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret = False
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6))
print (ret)

if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners)

    # Draw and display the corners
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners, ret)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.imwrite('Corners_detected.jpg', img, None)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, 
gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
h,  w = img.shape[:2]

newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))

# undistort
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
cv2.imwrite('calibration_result.png',dst)
```

In this code image 2.jpg is taken for calibration,

[This is the image considered for understanding of calibration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdYQH.jpg)

My code is detecting corners for only this image. It is not working fine with other checker board image.It is not able to detect corners. Why is it so ?

Comment: You don't seem to use the `images` array anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment and clarify some points. However, I will try to answer anyway. Given you have added the `print(ret)` I assume this is where your problem lies.

It looks like you are using the wrong checkerboard size in `cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6))`. I have found this function returns `False` given the wrong input dimension values.
This is als the case for the `objp` object.

Given the image, you are showing this should be `n-1` and `m-1` (where `n` and `m` are the checkboard dimensions).

**For your given image, this should be `cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9, 6))`**

Notice on the [opencv calibration example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) the checkerboard is an 8x7, hence the given 7x6 input value.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about the Camera Calibration method is that it sometimes will not recognize a Checkerboard grid that isn't the maximum size. You could most likely get away with 8,6 or 9,5 as the size. However, with 6,7 there is too much of a difference and so the method won't recognize it.

I don't have any research sources but I've tested this myself before.

Comment: Also this answer is 1.5 years late sorry!